# How can make my django datetime field to display seconds

Tags: python, mysql, django, datetime

I have a datetime field 'scantime' in my django model.

`scandate = models.DateTimeField(max_length=100)`

When I retrieve this from mysql database, it is displaying in my django UI like this: Oct. 16, 2014, 4:37 p.m.

But when I debug, this value is something like this: datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 13, 6, 8, 47, tzinfo = UTC).

Though seconds are stored in DB, django is not displaying seconds in the UI bydefault.

My template code is like this:

`{% for key,value in logdata.items %}
    <tr> 
        {% for item in value %}
        <td>{{ item }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
 {% endfor %}`

Is there any way that I can display seconds in UI? Please help me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try like this,

```
 <td>{{ item|date:'Y-m-d H:i:s' }}</td>
```

Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date